# BackSlashes not preserved when dropping file with no spaces in the name on shortcut to WSL bash script

Tags: parameters, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Windows 10, running Debian in WSL2, I have a desktop shortcut to a bash script.
I'd like to drag-and-drop a number of files onto the shortcut, and have the script process them. It works fine if there ARE spaces in the filename, but if there are no spaces, then the path ends up with all slashes removed. For example, `C:\Users\Me\file.txt` would become `C:UsersMefile.txt`

The shortcut which receives the dropped files is `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -- /home/myuser/bin/hi.sh`

The first two lines of the script "hi.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Received $@"
```

If I drop these files on it:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\file-no-spaces.wav
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\File With Spaces.wav
```

It outputs:

```
Received C:UsersMeDesktopfile-no-spaces.wav C:\Users\Me\Desktop\File With Spaces.wav
```

There are utilities like wslpath, but they're of no use if the initial files are already stripped. Any suggestions how to get windows to not strip out the backslashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of shortcut, create `hi.cmd` as follows :

```
@ECHO OFF
C:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -- /home/myuser/bin/hi.sh "%*"
```

and drag&drop files onto `hi.cmd`

*Update*
This seems to work, but you need to process each file separately:

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%x in (%*) do (
   C:/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -- /home/myuser/bin/hi.sh "%%~x"
)
```

Comment: Love the idea, but it's not quite working. Only one is good. Using hi.cmd with ```"%*"``` _file-no-spaces_ is good!  But _File With Spaces_ doesn't have any slashes. If I remove the quotes around %* then it's the opposite: _File With Spaces_ is good, _file-no-spaces_ has no slashes.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I'm going with this. `%~1` as opposed to %1 or %1%, is the only method that is consistent with having no quotes. So this loop then adds quotes and collects all the parameters into %params%

```
@echo off
:loop
  set "params=%params% "%~1^""
  shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto loop
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -- /home/rinzin/bin/hi.sh %params%
```

Comment: Why you are using `goto loop` instead of `for loop` ?